# LME with Random effects R code error message?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a random mixed effects model with CCT as the outcome and time*behavior as the main predictor interaction term. I'm having a hard time running the model, as this is my code and it keeps saying "unused argument" error message. I'm using the variable ID as the random effects variable, and this is my code. thank you!

```
model.set$f <- with(model.set, ID)
m <- lmer(CCT ~ time*behavior, random = ~ 1|f, data = model.set)
```

Answer (score 3):

The argument causing the error in your command is `random`: when using the function `lme4::lmer`, there is no "random" argument, the random effect is part of the main formula. The syntax you are using is specific to the function `nlme::lme`, which has a "random" argument to define random effects. See [here](https://freshbiostats.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/mixed-models-in-r-lme4-nlme-both/) for examples.

The following command should run without error:

```
m <- lmer(CCT ~ time * behavior + (1|f), data = model.set)
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I am getting this error: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
Warning in optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$pp), lower = rho$lower,  :
  convergence code -4 from nloptwrap: NLOPT_ROUNDOFF_LIMITED: Roundoff errors led to a breakdown of the optimization algorithm. In this case, the returned minimum may still be useful. (e.g. this error occurs in NEWUOA if one tries to achieve a tolerance too close to machine precision.) 1/2---

Comment: Warning in checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Warning in checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
Warning: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling

Comment: This is a good sign: it means that R understands your model and is trying to fit it to your data. Just follow the advice given in the error message: some variables are on a very different scale... consider rescaling them!

Comment: ANd maybe there is a problem with how you specified your model, but to help you with that, we will need more details on the data...

Comment: I would even suggest that you accept @VincentGuillemot's answer and post a new question that includes the new warnings, and some details about your input (e.g. `summary(model.set)`